# How to tell Django not to use the cache for a request?

Tags: python, django, caching

I am using Django's caching framework with Memcached:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#django-s-cache-framework

It's working great. The only issue I am having is sometimes, I want to make a request to my Django server and tell it to bypass the cache. But I couldn't find any documentation on this.

How do I make a request to a Django server and tell it to not use the cache for this particular request?

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development ?

Comment: There's a whole section on how to vary the caching on HTTP headers.

Comment: A dummy cache will disable caching for all requests for a view. In other words, a view is the smallest granularity of control you get. I am looking for request level granularity without implementing a custom cache if possible.

Answer (score 0):

How about put additional logic in request processor? For example, send additional header (or get or post parameter or cookie) and if header exists in request then bypass the cache.